# Retain files but exclude from compression R CMD build

Tags: r, package

I am creating an R package. I have several .csv files in the \data folder. The examples in this package refer to these .csv files. But when I run

```
system("R CMD build <pkg>")
```

it also does a gzip of these files. This means that the examples in the .Rd files will not apply as these refer to .csv files

How can I exclude the compression of these .csv files while retaining the files in the .tar.gz

I tried to add a rule to .Rbuildignore
^.*.csv$
but this removes the entire directory itself.

How can I inlcude this directory and all the files but exclude from compression.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build package with --no-resave-data option.

```
$ R CMD build --no-resave-data <pkg>
```

Comment: Thanks @Yueh, I got that. But now I find that when I run R CMD check <pkg> I get an error because the files were not gzipped. Any thoughts on that

Comment: Suppose you put a member.csv in data folder. DESCRIPTION file should add LazyData: TRUE. If you install and library this package, it will provide a variable named member.

Comment: By the way, you might use rdata instead of csv. This will help you with a more regular data structure than LazyData csv files.

Comment: No. My examples require CSV. Besides regular users of my package will prefer CSV to .RData. Ignore the error mentioned above. That was something I overlooked. Now it is fixed.